# Author name is not working on category page

Tags: author

On my category page post author name is not getting displayed

This is what I am using

```
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>
```

Here is my loop

```
<div class="a-article-wrapper row">
            <?php 
              $cat_name = 'category';
              $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $cat_name );
              $top_level_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $cat_name );
              foreach( $top_level_terms as $top_term ) 
              {
                if(!($top_term->parent))
                {
                  $child_terms = get_terms( $cat_name, array( 'child_of' => $top_term->term_id ));
                  //Parent Category Name
                  //echo '<div class="maincat-HC">'.$top_term->name .'</div>'; 
                  $top_id=$top_term->term_id;
                  if(count($child_terms)>0)
                  {
                    foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) 
                    {
                      $id=$child_term->term_id;
                      //Child category name
                      //echo '<ul class="hc-accordion"><li><div class="hc-subcat">' .$child_term->name .'</div>';

                      $myposts=get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'nopaging' => true,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => $cat_name,
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $id)
                        ))
                      );

                      foreach ($myposts as $mypost) { ?>




                        <div class="col-md-4 a-article-row">
                                    <?php 
                                      echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); 
                                    ?>
                            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($mypost->ID), 'full' );?>
                            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                <div class="archive-thumb-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')"></div>
                            <?php  } else { ?>
                                <div class="archive-thumb-img"></div>
                            <?php } ?>

                           <div class="article-detail">
                               <div class="category">
                                    <?php

                                        foreach($categories as $category) {
                                            if($category->parent){
                                                echo $category->name;
                                            }
                                        }  
                                    ?> 

                                </div>
                                <div class="a-article-title">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink($mypost);?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php echo mb_strimwidth( get_the_title(), 0, 45, '...' );  ?> 
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="author">
                                    <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>

                      <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
                    } 
                  }
                }
              }
            ?>
          </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom theme file for category pages? If so, can you share the code for your loop?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the author ID properly.

This line:

`<?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>`

Should be this:

`<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $mypost->post_author ); ?>`

Alternatively you could use `setup_postdata()` in your foreach loop to setup the global $post variable and make use of the template tag functions without having to pass in the IDs.

```
global $post;

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 a-article-row">
                <?php 
                  echo get_the_author_meta('display_name'); 
                ?>
        <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($mypost->ID), 'full' );?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <div class="archive-thumb-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')"></div>
        <?php  } else { ?>
            <div class="archive-thumb-img"></div>
        <?php } ?>

       <div class="article-detail">
           <div class="category">
                <?php

                    foreach($categories as $category) {
                        if($category->parent){
                            echo $category->name;
                        }
                    }  
                ?> 

            </div>
            <div class="a-article-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink($mypost);?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php echo mb_strimwidth( get_the_title(), 0, 45, '...' );  ?> 
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="author">
                <?php echo get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata();
```